# HTML form for multiple record

Tags: php, html

I wish to save multiple record within one from with nested loop as below.

```
<?php
   foreach($students as $student){
    foreach($student->$subjects as $subjects){
        <input name="grade[]" value="" />
    }
   }
?>
```

How to structure to get below `post['record']`?

```
[records] => array(3) {
    [0]=> array(3) {
            ["'student_id'"] => string(1) "1", ["'subject_id'"] => string(1) "4", ["'grade'"] => string(1) "A"
        },
    [1]=> array(3) {
            ["'student_id'"] => string(1) "1", ["'subject_id'"] => string(1) "2", ["'grade'"] => string(1) "B"
        },
    [2]=> array(3) {
            ["'student_id'"] => string(1) "2", ["'subject_id'"] => string(1) "3", ["'grade'"] => string(3) "A+"
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want but guessing you want to set up the *records* info so you can easily pull it into your report. If so, I expect I would take the *records* array are reformat it so the student id's and subject id's are keys. Then I could easily access them in the sort of loop you have in your question. If so let me know so I can give you an example what I mean.

Comment: bloodyknuckles, student_id and subject_id are keys, actually foreign keys in records table. Teacher will just input grade of related subject and click submit to save all record. What I need is I want to post as I described. what I need is  how to add `hidden input` in my loop. I am googling for answer for so long but have not got yet.

Comment: Yes, student_id and subject_id are database keys, but they are not PHP array keys. If they are made PHP array keys then accessing them is a piece of cake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you needing something like this:

```
$st = $student->id;
$su = $subject->id;
echo '<input type="text" name="grades[' . $st . '][' . $su . ']" value="" />';
```

Then in the PHP script that receives the POST you can access the grades as such:

```
foreach ( $_POST['grades'] as $student_id => $student_grades ) {
    foreach ( $student_grades as $subject_id => $grade ) {
        echo "student id: $student_id, ";
        echo "subject id: $subject_id, ";
        echo "grade:      $grade      <br>";
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
student id: 1, subject id: 4, grade: A
student id: 1, subject id: 2, grade: B
student id: 2, subject id: 3, grade: A+
```

Comment: Bloodyknuckles, Arr, Sorry. you misunderstand my issue. I want **HTML form** . That includes only one input textfield. Named Grade.  And That form will submit by post **array-data** as I described. The issue is I wish to generate **html form** to input grade. I don't have grade in `$students` array. I want to submit **Grade with Students Id and Subject Id** in post-data array.

Comment: Bloodyknuckles, Thank. I got two solutions from you and from Sagar. Both work like charm. Thank advanced. And I can't vote bcoz of my reputation is lower than 15.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like this? I assume you have  element already

**Form Part**

```
<?php
$students=array(
    array('student_id'=>1,'subject_id'=>4),
    array('student_id'=>1,'subject_id'=>2),
    array('student_id'=>2,'subject_id'=>3),

);
foreach($students as $student){
    echo('<input name="grade[]" value="">');
    echo('<input type="hidden" name="records[]" value="'.serialize($student).'">');
}
?>
```

**After Submit**

```
<?php
    $records=unserialize($_POST['records']);
    $grades=$_POST['grade'];
    // now mix both
    $i=0;
    foreach($grades as $grade) {
        $records[$i]['grade']=$grade;
        $i++;
    }

    print_r($records);

?>
```

Comment: Sagar, thank for your help. I already have elements from join tables. but Teacher will input grade to related subjects of each student. So I can't serialize without grade input.

Comment: Hi Ryan, I have changed the code, can you review?

Comment: Hi Sagar, Thank. Your solution also work. It's great. I can't vote bcoz my reputation lower than 15.